# Is there a function for finding the differences between the last time stamp of one netCDF file and the first time stamp of the next netCDF file?

Tags: python, numpy, netcdf, python-xarray

I have a list of netCDF files. I've opened each of these netCDF files in xarray like this:

```
files = ['file_1.nc', 'file_2.nc', 'file_3.nc', 'file_4.nc']

for file in files:
    xarray_object = xr.open_dataset(file)
```

I next want to take the last time stamp from file_1.nc and subtract it from the first time stamp from file_2.nc, and continue this pattern throughout the entire files list (so file_2.nc[first time stamp] - file_1.nc[last time stamp], file_3.nc[first time stamp] - file_2.nc[last time stamp], and so on).

I started attacking this problem by:

```
    time_diff = xarray_object['time'][-1] - xarray_object['time'][0]
```

But this only subtracts the last time stamp from the first time stamp of file_1.nc, then the last time stamp from the first time stamp of file_2.nc, and so on.

I'm not sure the best way to get the loop to look at the time stamps of two separate files at once.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I think you're mostly looking for `zip`?
https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/functions.html#zip

```py
# glob is convenient for getting multiple paths with a wildcard e.g.
import glob
import xarray as xr

paths = sorted(glob.glob("*.nc"))
datasets = [xr.open_dataset(path) for path in paths]

# Get the first time for the second dataset onward
first_times = [ds["time"][0] for ds in datasets[1:]]

# Get the last time, except for the last dataset
last_times [ds["time"][-1] for ds in datasets[:-1]]

# Use zip to go through both lists at once
time_deltas = [t1 - t0 for t0, t1 in zip(first_times, last_times)]
```

P.S.

With glob, you may want to check if the sorting goes as desired, you can always use the key argument, which takes a function, to make sure you're e.g. sorting by the number in the filename:

```py
unsorted = ["file_02", "file_1"]
print(sorted(unsorted))
```

More robustly, we could split on the underscore, and turn whatever comes after the underscore into an integer:

```py
print(sorted(unsorted, key=lambda x: int(x.split("_")[-1]))
```

Of course, if you just provide the list yourself, you're in full control anyway...